# How to reference a subarray of a two dimensional array as a single dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a two dimensional array myArray[a][b]
what is the most elegant way of referencing the
single dimension array myArray[a][2] in Java.

Comment: myArray[a][2] references only one element. Infact it has to be myArray[a-1][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood question correctly, this is it

```
    int a[][] = {{1,1,1},{2,2,2}, {3,3,3}};
    int[] a2 = a[2];
```

,

Comment: `a[0]` and `a[1]` are the only valid indexes there.